# PyQt5 SQLAlchemy QTableWidget запрос в БД по двойному клику

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, sqlalchemy

#### Задача:

Есть специальная форма для создания Преподавателя и записи его в БД. Необходимо по двойному клику на строчку в таблице открыть эту форму для редактирования существующей записи. Т.е. по двойному клику в БД должен пойти запрос вернуть данные по преподавателю (уникальное поле id and email) ввиде списка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Таблица преподавателей**

```
    self.teachers_table = QTableWidget(self)
    self.teachers_table_header_horizont = 
    ["full name on Russian", "full name on Latin", "native language",  "citizenship", "email", "phone number", "1C number"]                                self.teachers_table.setColumnCount(len(self.teachers_table_header_horizont))
    self.teachers_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.teachers_table_header_horizont)

    self.paint_teacher_table()
```

**Отрисовка таблицы на основе полученных данных из БД**

```
    def paint_teacher_table(self):
        self.teachers_lst = controller.load_teacher_list()
        self.teachers_table.setRowCount(len(self.teachers_lst))
        for i in range(self.teachers_table.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.teachers_table.columnCount()):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(self.teachers_lst[i][j])
                item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                self.teachers_table.setItem(i, j, item)
        self.teachers_table.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

**Получение списка учителей из базы данных для дальнейшей отрисовки в таблице**

```
    def load_teacher_list():
        DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        teacher_lst = []
        for teacher in DBSession().query(Teacher).all():
        teacher_lst.append([teacher.full_name_on_lat,
                            teacher.full_name_on_rus,
                            teacher.native_lang_id,
                            teacher.citizenship_id,
                            teacher.email,
                            teacher.telephone_number,
                            teacher.C1_number])
        return teacher_lst
```

#### Проблема:

Понятия не имею как по двойному клику на любую ячейку в строке открыть окно для редактирования преподавателя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привожу пример отлова двойного клика на ячейку таблицы и показа диалога редактирования:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QApplication, QInputDialog
)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(3)
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.on_cell_item_clicked)

        rows = ['Vasya', 'Petya', 'Masha']

        for i, value in enumerate(rows):
            self.table.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(i + 1)))
            self.table.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(value))

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

    def on_cell_item_clicked(self, item):
        print(item)

        new_text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Change Name', 'Change Name', text=item.text())
        if ok:
            item.setText(new_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** Для своих данных, возможно, придется делать собственный диалог, наследуя класс `QDialog` или его наследников. В ответе просто пример вызова диалога. В реальный задаче такой диалог не нужен, т.к. редактирование текста ячейки можно двойным кликом в самой ячейке.